# thread execution example in c++ concurrency in action

Tags: c++, multithreading

following code is a scoped thread example in c++ concurrency in action. but i has a question when run this example in xcode5.1, because the `Scoped_thread t` is join in its destructor function, destructor of t is run in the end of thread main()? so no matter how long I has the main() thread sleep, the main's output is before the t's output, but the answer is not? anyone can help me explain this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;



struct Scoped_thread
{
  std::thread sthread;

  Scoped_thread(std::thread tmp):sthread(std::move(tmp))
  {
    if (!sthread.joinable())
    {
        cout<<"error on contructor a scoped thread"<<endl;
    }
  }

 ~Scoped_thread()
 {
    sthread.join();
 }

     Scoped_thread(Scoped_thread& tmp) = delete;
     Scoped_thread& operator =(const Scoped_thread& tmp) = delete;
}; 

void hello_scoped_thread()
{
    cout<<"this is scoped thread output"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    Scoped_thread t((std::thread(hello_scoped_thread)));
   //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

   cout<<"this is in main thread"<<endl;

   return 0;

}
```

**edit plus**:i want to know when the main thread known t thread is joined, when main do destruct the t? / during compiler parse the code or sometime like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thread is running asynchronously, so there should be not too much concern about the order of actions between the thread and main.  The actions are normally done as fast as possible, so when 1 thread waits, the others can just continue.

The scoped thread class just takes care that the main thread waits until the new thread finishes at the end of the scope, which is the end of the `main()` function, by joining.

Comment: hi, first of all, thanks for you answer so quickly, i am new to stackoverflow; can i understand by this: when i create the  Scoped_thread t, this thread will run immediately, no matter whether your do join or detach later, in above code, if t finish before main, so t just exit, do nothing with main? but if main finish early, when it exit, it will destruct the local variable t, so it will evoke the t's destructor, it found t is join in, so it will wait?

Comment: Yes, it will run immediately, but joining means continuing with the main thread after the join() statement when the new thread has finished, so it doesn't care which thread is first finished, when the thread is joinable, it will be cleaned up at that point.

Comment: sorry, i am not native english speaker, i cannot well understood this line "when the thread is joinable, it will be cleaned up at that point"?; would you explain me that when main thread finish early what will happen? otherwise t thread finish early? thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't it be worthwhile to revisit the join section (2.1.2) in the book? I'm sure it is explained better there than I could in a couple of lines.

Comment: thanks to your advice, i have search other material about join()(because i think the author doesn't explain much about this), but i still have a question? when main() thread known thread t is joined to it, because it is in t's destructor; It is known until the main to destruct the t variable? or when compiler parse the code, it found the t.join()?

Comment: At the end of main(), t is cleaned up, so its destructor is called.  In the destructor join() is called.  The function of join() is to wait until the thread has finished and to clean up the thread resources.  How the main thread finds out that the new thread is finished is up to the operating system.